# Laravel Undefined variable: Name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

hello I'm trying to pass the $Name to the view and i cant seem to get it to work and the video i followed line for line didn't seem to work any help would be great appreciated.

Edit. I know this is Novice level but its giving the most trouble in my project right now.

Controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

abstract class RequestController extends BaseController
{
    public function GetName(){
        $name = ['one','two','three'];
        return view::make('home', ['name' => $name]);
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('home', 'RequestController@GetName');
```

View

```
@foreach( $name as $names)
<tr>
<th>{{ $names }}</th>
</tr>
@endForeach
```

Error

```
ErrorException in d223bf579fc7c74c7e9ee61a6d17702e line 399:
Undefined variable: name (View: D:\Xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\home.blade.php)
in d223bf579fc7c74c7e9ee61a6d17702e line 399
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('D:\Xampp\htdocs\blog\storage\framework\views/d223bf579fc7c74c7e9ee61a6d17702e', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in CompilerEngine.php line 58
at CompilerEngine->get('D:\Xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views/home.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in View.php line 135
at View->getContents() in View.php line 106
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 80
at View->render() in Response.php line 51
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 198
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1229
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 113
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 45
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Authenticate), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(HomeController), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), '\Bestmomo\Scafold\Http\Controllers\HomeController', 'index') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 708
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 710
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: Why did you define RequestController as abstract? Please remove abstract not necessary

Comment: Can you include complete code for `RequestController` I will like to see what your constructor looks like. Also try `return view('home', ['home'=>$home])`

Comment: what view file is that you are showing us as 'View' ?

Comment: the home view file when a user first logs in with default auth @lagbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller

```
return view('home')->with('name', $name);
```

And in your view do the foreach that you have already and it should work as expected.

**Tip :**

To debug this you shall Just do [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) etc.,

Also Make sure that you're calling the proper function in the controller from your route

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
        return View::make( 'home' ,compact('name'));
```

or

```
        return View::make('home', ['name' => $name]);
```

also add at the top:

```
        use \View as View;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
view('home', compact('name'));
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to complement it with context, detailed information and/or code examples. The _Post Answer_ button should be used only for **complete answers to the question**.